# std::array class member set during compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class with private member `std::array<int,10> m_arr;` which contains zeros by default, but in one case it must be set to something else.
There is a setter for that class

```
void setArray(const std::array<int,10>& arr)
{
    m_arr=arr;
}
```

However I was wondering if the setting can be done compile time somehow for that specific case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on what exactly distinguishes that use case?

Comment: It should be possible when `const std::array<int,10>& arr` param is known at compile time. If it's users input etc. it's not possible

Comment: In that once case do all of the values need to be something other than 0 or will they have different values?

Comment: `const std::array<int,10>& arr` is known at compile time, not user input and the values are different for zero.

Comment: you need `constexpr`, not just `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be the following one:

```
#include<utility>
#include<array>

struct S {
    constexpr S(): arr{} { }

    template<std::size_t... I>
    constexpr S(std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>): arr{ I... } { }

    std::array<std::size_t, 10> arr;
};

int main() {
    constexpr S s1{};
    constexpr S s2{std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1>{}};
    // equivalent to: constexpr S s3{std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>{}};
    constexpr S s3{std::make_index_sequence<10>{}};
}
```

Note that `integer_sequence` is part of the C++14 revision.
Anyway, you can find online an implementation of such a structure that is suitable for C++11 based projects.